# Why won't this work? If selected item from list box is string then set different string as number

Tags: c#

Okay i'll probably get a lot of crap for this but I'm new. Why won't this work?

```
        string serviceCode;
        string Next_Day_Air_Early_AM;
        string inserviceCode = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (inserviceCode = Next_Day_Air_Early_AM)
           { 
            serviceCode = 14.ToString(); 
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the assignment operator `=` in the `if` condition instead of the equality operator `==`.  The expression in an `if` condition must evaluate to type `bool`.  Also, you're using the variable `Next_Day_Air_Early_AM` before you've initialized it.